# Difference between Keras 2.0.8 and 2.1.5?

Tags: keras

I am training a GAN and I see that my performance is very different on my CPU and GPU. I noticed that on the GPU installation, it is 2.0.8 and for CPU it is 2.1.5. On a separate machine with keras+tf GPU I get the same performance as the CPU one from before, the keras version is 2.1.6.

Is this expected? In the keras release notes I did not find anything that would change the way my training works.

The performance with the new one is better in many senses. Much faster convergence (10x less epochs required) but the images are less smooth sometimes.

Comment: what gpu and what cuda version?

Comment: Nvdia Tesla cuda 8